Display last refreshed date in kpi card
I want a card that displays the date time in the following format: "last refreshed on 03 Sep 2024,  09:30 AM IST" whenever the dashboard is refreshed the date should update to that time only and display the date time when the dashboard is refreshed everytime in power bi
display last refreshed date whenever the dashboard is published

A simple search on the web: Add last refresh date based on a Power BI or OData query

maybe you can try to create a new blank query in PQ
= DateTime.LocalNow()

then click to Table

then you can add this time to a card. Every time you refresh the report, the time will update automatically.
